# modifying the variable instance while doing list comprehension

Tags: python-2.7

Shouldn't the list comprehension restrict the variable scope.

```
user = <user1>
project.users = [<user1>, <user2>, <user3>, <user4>]
project_usernames  = [user.username for user in project.users]
```

I am generating the list project_usernames using list comprehension on project.users. 
But it is modifying the user to `<user4>` which was earlier `<user1>`.

I am using above flow in one of my project but because of this bug it was not working.

later when I changed the variable "user" in list comprehension, it worked properly.

entity within `<>` refers to `<object>`

I know that the interpreter works line by line, but shouldn't the scope of variable used in list comprehension die once the iteration is over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Python 2.x 'feature', where the variable you use inside of the list comprehension (in your case, `user`) becomes part of the surrounding scope (in Python 3, it is treated like a generator - see [here](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/from-list-comprehensions-to-generator.html) for the breakdown from Guido himself). Assuming that you are iterating through your list (as opposed to needing to have everything available in memory), you could set it up like a generator by just changing the brackets to parentheses:

```
>>> user = 'test'
>>> l = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
>>> users = (user[4] for user in l)
>>> users
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f6a89507140>
>>> user
'test'
>>> for num in users:
...   print num
...
1
2
3
```